# Intermittent socket hang up

Tags: node.js, angular

I am getting socket hang up. The issue is intermittent. For some cases api is getting called as expected and for other cases I get this socket hang up error.
[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGf3c.png)

I am basically calling an API from my UI which is sometimes giving the result as expected but sometimes fails with socket hang up. I am using got HTTP request library for Node.js

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.